# Comando de entrada prompt-sync no Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou estudando o Node, e cheguei em uma dúvida sobre a implementação desse pacote npm no meu projeto. Já instalei esse pacote no projeto, e também consegui obter os dados do comando de entrada com sucesso, através do require():

```
const prompt = require ('prompt-sync') ({sigint: true});

const x = prompt('Digite x: ')
console.log(`x = ${x}`)
```

Entretanto está ocorrendo um erro no meu programa pelo fato de estar usando duas formas diferentes de importação de módulos (importei alguns módulos em outra parte do projeto com o *import*). Por isso, gostaria de saber a forma correta de importar esse pacote com o *import* para não gerar essa incompatibilidade no sistema. Eis a forma em que tentei colocar o *import*:

```
import prompt from 'prompt-sync';


const x = prompt('Digite x: ')

console.log(`x = ${x}`)
```

Comment: Faltou explicar se houve um erro, e qual foi.

Comment: O erro aconteceu por eu não saber em qual pasta do prompt-sync colocar o 'export'. Eu estava só importando sem colocar o export no arquivo que queria exportar (pq n sei onde devo colocar). Além disso, não sei em qual "package.json" colocar o type: module

Comment: Você falou que "estava". Já conseguiu resolver? Caso não, o `prompt-sync` que você tenta importar é um projeto seu, ou é uma livraria/projeto já existente, feita por um terceiro?

Comment: Falei "estava" por que estava me referindo ao momento que surgiu a dúvida e que não tinha reparado nesses detalhes que citei no comentário, perdão, me expressei mal. O **prompt-sync** é um módulo que pode ser instalado no node através do npm. É uma forma de trabalhar com comandos de entrada para o programa receber dados do usuário (como se fosse um input dos navegadores)

Comment: Se o prompt-sync é o do npm, você não mexe em nada nele. Não precisa colocar export nenhum. É só abrir a documentação dele e ver o que você precisa importar no seu próprio código.

Comment: O SO  inglês tem uma resposta para você, veja se te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852175/convert-prompt-sync-require-into-import-method

Comment: Certo, irei conferir. Muito obrigado!